# How to set individual widget sizes in Qt Layout?

Tags: qt, layout

I'm working on a C++ Qt GUI to remote control a ROS robot. The major part of the GUI is gonna be showing multiple camera images. So far I put a `QGridLayout` as central widget in which I added four `QLabel`. I want to show the camera installed in the front of the robot in a bigger label than the ones on the side or in the rear.

Camera layout:

[image: camera layout]

I have tried to use this function

`grid->addWidget(labelMid, 0, 5, 10, 6);`

where the last two numbers indicate the rows and columns the widget is spanning. However that was not exactly convincing as the rows and columns don't seem to all have the same width/height.

Stretchfactors seem to be only existant for whole rows or columns not just certain cells so that is no option either.

Does someone know a way to set this kind of layout? I don't have to necessarily stick to the gridlayout.

Comment: It is difficult to see your precise problem without more code, but generally speaking you should be able to use the grid layout to do what you want.  Bear in mind the widgets' size hints also play a role in all this, as does their size policies.

You should be able to achieve a similar layout using nested vertical/horizontal box layouts with spacers and stretch factors, but that seems messier to me.

Comment: Well the thing is there really is no more code. Let's say I have `grid->addWidget(label1, 0, 5, 10, 6);` for the big label in the middle and `grid->addWidget(label2, 11, 6, 3, 4)`  for the one in the bottom. I expected the screen to be kind of parted in 13 rows with equal height. The first label should use 10 rows, the second one 3. That is not the case. The first one merely uses a little more than half the vertical screen space. The horizontal space distribution seems to work in that way. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Your assumption about how space distribution works are not correct:  from [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#details):  "Note that the columns and rows are not equally wide or tall. If you want two columns to have the same width, you must set their minimum widths and stretch factors to be the same yourself. You do this using setColumnMinimumWidth() and setColumnStretch()."  Your widgets are taking the indicated row/column spans but they're not all the same size (by design).

Comment: You must ask yourself what size you want your widgets to take, some fixed size, a relative size of the window size etc. QGridLayout is not always the best choice if you just want to center or align a few widgets, [`QBoxLayout::addStretch`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) can be simpler and powerful in vertical/horizontal layouts.